# Is there any way to get the date N days from now in AIML 1.0?

Tags: aiml

I need the date (say) 7 days from now as a  variable but couldn't find any implementation for the same for AIML version 1.0

Comment: You can only do this in AIML 1.0 by coding a calendar function yourself.

Answer (score -1):

You can put the date of today in a variable and use a loop with successor to add 7days.
Or build a map with all the dates and use a loop with this map to add 7days.

Comment: maps and loops are only available in AIML 2. You cannot do this in AIML 1.0